# Lightweight WSO2 ID provided Access Token validation?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, wso2-identity-server

How does one validate an OAuth 2.0 access token obtained from a WSO2 Identity Server?

More specifically, I am looking for a lightweight alternative that:

- does *not* involve direct or indirect SOAP requests (such as using [stubs to call an admin service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Calling+Admin+Services)).
- has a small set of dependencies (in software libraries and/or required other middleware components).

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm looking for a way for Apache/Nginx to validate an `access_token` but found little to no info...

Comment: Nope. Nothing so far, sorry.

Comment: what about calling the rest endpoint ? https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Invoke+the+OAuth+Introspection+Endpoint